# Bootstrap validation error causing form alignment issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, alignment

In this simple example, when I have a validation error on the First Name input box on the left side of the form, the E-Mail form element gets pushed down the page.

[image: Picture of form issue on left side]

When I have the same error on the right side of the form though, this behavior does not happen.

[image: Picture of no issue on the right side]

I don't see any difference in the code.  Here are some screen shots. I was unable to get this to work in jsfiddle or codepen, so here is the link to the test page and I've also pasted my html below:

https://www.blastyourresume.com/testing/formalignment/test.cfm

To reproduce the error on that page, type something in the firstname field, then delete it.  If you repeat this process on the right side, you don't get the same behavior.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" align="center">
    <form name="frmSignup" id="frmSignup" method="post">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="50" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="50" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label>E-Mail Address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                <label>Confirm E-Mail Address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm E-Mail" id="confirmemail" name="confirmemail" maxlength="100" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **Flex approach**

   add `display:flex` to your parent container. Display flex will make
   your columns equal height.

   ```
   #frmSignup {
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: flex;
       -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   ```
2. **Absolute positioning of error messages.**

   ```
   .form-group {
       position: relative;
   }

   .errormessageclass {
       position: absolute;
       top: 100%;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```

Comment: the second approach helped me solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when validation message is shown for the first name input it causes email field to be pushed left and confirm email goes to the next row. I found that it could be fixed if you wrap you form groups in `<div class="row"></div>` like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
        <div class='form-group>first name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
        <div class='form-group>last name</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
        <div class='form-group>email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="">
        <div class='form-group>confirm email</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxgBQr?editors=1010)

But it sound like a rough hack. 
I also would be grateful to get an explanation of why pushing effect happens.

Comment: Is that a hack or a necessity? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: @ManojKumar as you want to use the bootstrap grid to format form - it's more like necessity (yes, I know all col(s) must have a parent element with the class row. I am just not sure that this is the best way to style form to be displayed in two columns. Also, wrapping in row cause following rows  "jump down"  when validation message appears. (because of height change).